# JavaScript Function Randomly Broke in IE9

Tags: javascript

I'm having issue with my site where the main nav no longer works in IE9.  It worked before, but then all of a sudden, it stopped working.  Strangely, if I visit the site on IE9, they work, but then when I ctrl+f5 the page, then it break.

I'm assuming there is a problem in my custom.js file as that's the file with my main "Nav Bar" js coding.  I am not sure if it's coded entirely properly, but the site works perfectly in chrome, firefox, safari, so I don't really feel like the JS is messed up.

custom.js is right here: (focus on [4] Nav Bar I'm Assuming)

```
/* --------------------------------------------------------------

INDEX:

[1] Search
[2] Popout Window
[3] Form Numbers
[4] Nav Bar
[5] Smooth Scroll
[6] Similar Pages Sidebar
[7] Estimate Form

-------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* --------------------------------------------------------------

[1*] Search

-------------------------------------------------------------- */

document.getElementById('headerSearch').onsubmit = function() {
    window.location = "javascript:poptastic('http://www.google.com/search?q=site:northtownsremodeling.com ' + document.getElementById('headerInput').value);"
      return false;}

/* --------------------------------------------------------------

[2*] Popout Window

-------------------------------------------------------------- */

var newwindow; function poptastic(url){
  newwindow=window.open(url,'name', 'height=800,width=1020,scrollbars=yes');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}}

/* --------------------------------------------------------------

[3*] Form Numbers

-------------------------------------------------------------- */

jQuery(function($){
    $("#menu-primary-number").mask("(999) 999-9999");
    $("#menu-zip").mask("99999");
});

/* --------------------------------------------------------------

[4*] Set Selected Menu Items & Hide

-------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*START FUNCTION*/
$(function() {

    $("#header-subnav ul").hide();
    $('.menu-option-set a[data-subid]').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $s = $("#" + $(this).attr('data-subid'));                
        if($s.is(':hidden')) {
            $("#header-subnav").removeClass('hidden');
            $("#header-subnav ul").hide();
            $s.show();
        } else {
            $s.hide();
            $("#header-subnav").addClass('hidden');
        }
    });

    $('.menu-option-set a').click(function()
    {
        // if clicked item is selected then deselect it
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected'))
        {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }

        // otherwise deselect all and select just this one
        else
        {
            $('.menu-option-set a').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    });
});

/* --------------------------------------------------------------

[5*] Smooth Scroll

-------------------------------------------------------------- */
$(function() {
    $('.navbar a, .scroll a, .smoothscroll a').bind('click',function(event){
        var $anchor = $(this);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 850,'easeInOutExpo');
        /*
        if you don't want to use the easing effects:
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1000);
        */
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

/* --------------------------------------------------------------

[6*] Similar Pages Sidebar

-------------------------------------------------------------- */
$(function() {
  $("a.show-similar-pages").click(function(e) {
    $("#sidebar").removeClass('mobile-phone-hide');
    $("#show-similar-pages").addClass('hidden');
    $("#hide-similar-pages").removeClass('hidden');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $("a.hide-similar-pages").click(function(e) {
    $("#sidebar").addClass('mobile-phone-hide');
    $("#hide-similar-pages").addClass('hidden');
    $("#show-similar-pages").removeClass('hidden');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});

/* --------------------------------------------------------------

[7*] Estimate Form

-------------------------------------------------------------- */
$(function() {
    // Setup any needed variables.
    var $form   = $('.estimate-menu-form'),
        $loader = '<img src="/img/loader.gif" height="11" width="16" alt="Loading..." />';

    $form.append('<div id="response" class="hidden">');
    var $response = $('#response');

    // Do what we need to when form is submitted.
    $form.on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function(e){

        // Hide any previous response text and show loader
        $response.hide().html( $loader ).show();

        // Make AJAX request 
        $.post('/resource/script/estimate-menu-send.php', $form.serialize(), function( data ) {

            // Show response message
            $response.html( data );

            // Scroll to bottom of the form to show respond message
            var bottomPosition = $form.offset().top + $form.outerHeight() - $(window).height();

            if( $(document).scrollTop() < bottomPosition )
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop : bottomPosition });

            // If form has been sent succesfully, clear it
            if( data.indexOf('success') !== -1 )
                $form.find('input:not(input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"]), textarea, select').val('').attr( 'checked', false );

        });


        // Cancel default action
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});/*END FUNCTION*/
```

Here is the HTML for the header nav:

```
<div id="header-bottom">
    <nav>
      <ul class="menu-option-set">
        <li><a href="/" <?php echo $home ?>>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-subid="services"<?php echo $services ?>>Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-subid="gallery"<?php echo $gallery ?>>Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-subid="customer"<?php echo $customer ?>>Customer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-subid="about"<?php echo $about ?>>About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-subid="contact"<?php echo $contact ?>>Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-subid="estimate"<?php echo $estimate ?>>Estimate</a></li>
        <li><form id="headerSearch" class="textcenter headerSearch" method="get"><input id="headerInput" type="text" name="search"/></form></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="header-subnav" class="hidden">
    <nav>
      <ul id="services">
        <li><a href="/bathroom/"<?php echo $bathroom ?>>Bathroom</a></li>
        <li><a href="/kitchen/"<?php echo $kitchen ?>><s>Kitchen</s></a></li>
        <li><a href="/accessibility/"<?php echo $accessibility ?>><s>Accessibility</s></a></li>
        <li><a href="/window/"<?php echo $window ?>><s>Windows</s></a></li>
        <li><a href="/deck/"<?php echo $deck ?>><s>Decks</s></a></li>
        <li><a href="/siding/"<?php echo $siding ?>><s>Siding</s></a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="gallery">
        <li><a href="/gallery.php"<?php echo $photo ?>>Photo Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="/project.php"<?php echo $project ?>>Project Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="/before-and-after.php" <?php echo $before_and_after ?>><s>Before &amp; After</s></a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="customer">
        <li><a href="/coupons.php"<?php echo $coupons ?>><s>Coupons</s></a></li>
        <li><a href="/testimonials.php"<?php echo $testimonials ?>>Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="/things-to-know.php"<?php echo $things_to_know ?>>Things to Know</a></li>
        <li><a href="/financing.php"<?php echo $financing ?>>Financing</a></li>
        <li><a href="/reviews.php"<?php echo $reviews ?>>Reviews</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="about">
        <li><a href="/about.php"<?php echo $about_us ?>>About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/privacy.php"<?php echo $privacy ?>>Privacy Policy</a></li>
        <li><a href="/alliances.php"<?php echo $alliances ?>>Strategic Alliances</a></li>
        <li><a href="/certified-contractor.php"<?php echo $certified_contractor ?>>Certified Contractor</a></li>
        <li><a href="/awards-and-accreditations.php"<?php echo $awards_and_accreditations ?>>Accreditations</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="contact">
        <li><a href="/contact.php"<?php echo $contact_us ?>>Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/employment.php"<?php echo $employment ?>>Employment</a></li>
        <li><a href="/estimate.php"<?php echo $request_estimate ?>>Request Estimate</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="estimate">
        <li>Menu estimate Form coming soon</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Mind you, this all worked fine in IE9, but randomly broke, I didn't change the HTML, It must be something with the JS.

Thanks guys, I really appreciate it!

**EDIT: I'm sorry, I didn't even post the site that you could view the problem at.  It can be seen here: http://www.remodeling-buffalo.com**

Comment: What script errors do you see in the error console?  Is all javascript that references the DOM being run AFTER the DOM is loaded?

Comment: Come on here @Flip4Life.  You post a question.  We ask some clarifying questions and you're not around to respond?  That's not the best way to use StackOverflow.  You should check-in within the next 15-30 minutes after asking a question to see if people understood it and/or had questions.  This will be your loss as most traffic sees your question in the first 30 minutes and if it's confusing and you are non-responsive in that time period, you will miss most chances for help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just got my wisdom teeth out this afternoon and I ended up being in a lot of pain and laid down to shortly after to find myself passed out.  I just woke up a second ago as I knew I posted this and rushed to my computer.  And I see no script errors in the error console.  I never said that I saw errors, I just mentioned that it wasn't working in IE9 for some reason.  I assumed that it had to be the JS as I never changed the HTML and it used to work.  Also, I have the JS ran at the bottom of the document, under the DOM.  Thanks, and I'm sorry - Alex

Comment: I can sympathize on the wisdom teeth.  Not fun.  Can you post the actual generated HTML that the browser sees, not the PHP template.  We need to get this into an actual non-working jsFiddle in order to see what is happening.  When you say "not working" and "broke", what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I just added the URL to the site up in the question above.  As can be seen in a browser such as Chrome or Firefox, the header nav upon clicking unhides it's child <ul>.  But in IE9, it simply does nothing of the matter, upon clicking the navigation, it doesn't un-hide the child which I feel would have to be an error with the JS above labeled: "[4] Nav Bar".  I'm confused by what you mean about posting the generated HTML that the browser sees, as that's what I did above?  The only PHP in their says whether it should be highlighted or not, nothing that would affect this? Thanks again.

Comment: You can replace all of this: `$form.find('input:not(input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"]), textarea, select').val('').attr( 'checked', false );
` with `form.reset();`.

Comment: There's all this sort of PHP template stuff: `<?php echo $photo ?>`.  All that stuff makes it so we can't actually use the HTML ourselves in a test.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the suggestion @RobG, but I just tried replacing it, and it didn't reset the form upon success like the other method did.  Are you sure I can substitute it in my situation?  Thanks -Alex

Comment: @Flip4Life—Make sure you are calling the form's reset method, not jQuery's. Since there is only one form, then `document.forms.headerSearch.reset();` or perhaps `$form[0].reset()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a script error in IE9 that is stopping the execution of some of your javascript.  It appears that you don't have the .mask method defined for jQuery in this:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#menu-primary-number").mask("(999) 999-9999");
    $("#menu-zip").mask("99999");
});
```

And, it may be that exceptions thrown in a ready handler have different consequences in some browsers.

---

It also looks to me like you're trying to run some javascript before the DOM has loaded such as:

```
document.getElementById('headerSearch').onsubmit = function() {
    window.location = "javascript:poptastic('http://www.google.com/search?q=site:northtownsremodeling.com ' + document.getElementById('headerInput').value);"
      return false;}
```

which would cause it to fail.  Since you're using jQuery and already have some ready handler function blocks, you should put all code that references the DOM upon initalization in one of those document.ready blocks.

Comment: Oh, wow.  I took that out for now as I didn't make the form up yet, and it fixed it.  Such a stupid mistake, the question I have though is how did you view the script error in IE9?  I don't know of a method to view errors in IE, only Chrome and Firefox.  Thanks so much! (:

Comment: @Flip4Life - Hit F12 to open the debug window in IE.  Then click on the console tab.  Then, you may have to hit F5 in your page to reload it to capture the errors.

Comment: about your recent update, how I am calling that in before the DOM has loaded, What can I do to make it so it doesn't load before the DOM?  The issue is that I made this entire custom.js up myself and don't really understand JS all that well.  I just know that everything that's in there currently works how I want it to and that's fine.  How can I make it so it loads after the DOM is loaded?  PS. Thanks so much for telling me about IE console.  It no longer produces errors and is fixed.  Thanks again!

Comment: In `custom.js`, you have `$(function() {  code here })` construct for jQuery.  The code between the braces is not executed until the DOM is ready as jQuery waits until the page has been loaded before running that code.

Comment: **EDIT**: from this, I ran through my site really quickly and noticed another error.  One that comes out on all of my "gallery" pages.  It says: "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'prototype': object is null or undefined filter-masonry.js, line 68 character 9"  --> The file that it is referring to can be seen [HERE](http://www.remodeling-buffalo.com/resource/js/filter-masonry.js), right under where it says: "List Items Masonry Center".  The Gallery page can be seen [HERE](http://www.remodeling-buffalo.com/gallery.php).  Do you by chance understand this error or no?  Thanks again!

Comment: PS. I added in `$(function() {` to the code in my custom.js file.  It is still working fine now, so thank you.

Comment: `$.Isotope` is probably some other [jQuery plug-in](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) that you have not loaded into the page.

Comment: but I do have it being called in right below that file: <script src="/resource/js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script> Should I swap the two so it loads jquery.isotope.min.js and THEN loads filter-masonry.js?

Comment: Okay, that seems to be the error, it calls out to a file before that file has been loaded yet.  I swapped around the order and it fixed it.  Is that not the best method to fix it though?  Should I instead be adding some kind of "wait for this file to load before executing"?

Comment: @Flip4Life - Scripts in `<script>` tags in the HTML file are run in the order they are listed in the HTML file.  So, just list them in the proper order and things should work.  You generally load your script libraries first, then any add-ons/plug-ins for those, then your own custom code.